# Помогите осознать

Tags: php

Есть такая задача:

1. Есть форма с двумя инпутами Номер документа и Дата документа
2. Есть БД с таблицей,в которой 2 столба: в одном номера документа,в
   другом даты документов.
3. Как сделать так чтобы проверялось сочетание данных из формы и
   сочетание из таблицы (причем именно сочетание,а то у меня получилось так что номер проверяется а дата проходит любая из второго столбца)

```
 $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Ошибка соединения с БД: " . mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db('reestr', $link) or die ('Ошибка в выборе БД : ' . mysql_error()); 
 $blankid = $_POST['blankid']; 
 $blankdate = $_POST['blankdate']; 
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blanki WHERE blank_id=$blankid");
 if(mysql_num_rows($query)){ echo "GOOD"; } else echo "shit";
```

Comment: Добавьте ваш код

Comment: Приведите пример кода, укажите какую БД используете

Comment: вот код
использую mySQL
<?php

$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Ошибка соединения с БД: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('reestr', $link) or die ('Ошибка в выборе БД : ' . mysql_error());

$blankid = $_POST['blankid'];
$blankdate = $_POST['blankdate'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blanki WHERE blank_id=$blankid");
if(mysql_num_rows($query)){
    echo "GOOD";
}
else echo "shit";

?>

Comment: Вы правда хотите *проверять сочетание*? Или, может, Вы на самом деле хотите, чтобы после выбора в одном из списков во втором оставались только те варианты (пары значений), которые присутствуют в таблице?

Comment: мне нужно чтобы введенной паре данных:Номеру и Дате нашлось или не нашлось соответсвие из базы данных,тоже парой:из одной колонки номер,из другой дата

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем решил вопрос вот так,все спасибо

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Ошибка соединения с БД: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('reestr', $link) or die ('Ошибка в выборе БД : ' . mysql_error());

$blankid = $_POST['blankid'];
$blankdate = $_POST['blankdate'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blanki WHERE blank_id='".$blankid."' AND blank_data='".$blankdate."' ");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($numrows!=0)
{
  if($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
      $db_blankid = $row['blank_id'];
      $db_blankdate = $row['blank_data'];
  }
  else echo "UZHAS";
      if($blankid == $db_blankid && $blankdate == $db_blankdate) echo "GOOD";
      else echo "govno";
}
else echo "polnoe dermo";

?>
```

Comment: Бррррррррррррррр...